# SSH from jenkins to same host

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins instance running on my raspberry pi 3 and i also have my (simple) apache webserver running on the same raspberry pi.

I've got a pipeline from jenkins to fetch a git repo, build it and put (via scp) the build files on my webserver.

I have a ssh private/public key setup, but it's a bit stupid (?) to have an ssh key when the jenkins is hosted on the same 'machine' with the same ip address no?

Anyway, on my raspberry pi i have setup the autorized keys file and the known host file with the public key on it, and i've added the private key to jenkins via the ssh-agent plugin.

Here you have my jenkinsfile thats being used by jenkins to define my pipeline:

```
node{
    stage('Checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }

    stage('install') {
        nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'nodeJS10.5.0') {
            sh "npm install"
        }
    }

    stage('build'){
        nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'nodeJS10.5.0') {
            sh "npm run build"
        }
    }

    stage('connect ssh and remove files') {
        sshagent (credentials: ["0527982f-7794-45d0-99b0-135c868c5b36"]) {
            sh "ssh pi@123.456.789.123 -p 330 rm -rf /var/www/html/*"
        }
    }


    stage('upload new files'){
        sshagent (credentials: ["0527982f-7794-45d0-99b0-135c868c5b36"]) {
            sh "scp -P 330 -r ./build/* pi@123.456.789.123:/var/www/html"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output from the second to last job that is failing:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // nodejs
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (connect ssh and remove files)
[Pipeline] sh
[Deploy_To_Production] Running shell script
+ ssh pi@123.456.789.123 -p 330 rm -rf /var/www/html/asset-manifest.json /var/www/html/css /var/www/html/favicon.ico /var/www/html/fonts /var/www/html/images /var/www/html/index.html /var/www/html/manifest.json /var/www/html/service-worker.js /var/www/html/static /var/www/html/vendor
Host key verification failed.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 255
Finished: FAILURE
```

Note: I've changed my IP address and my ssh port for security reasons.

Manually i can ssh to my raspberry pi and i can execute the commands manually from my laptop (both from same and other domain works).

I've also port forwarded the local ip so that i connect to it via SSH when i'm not home.

I guess I'm doing something wrong with the SSH keys etc, but i'm no expert whatsoever!

Can anyone help?

Comment: For future reference, it would be good to use rsync here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed that the host key verification was failing. I think this was due to not trusting the host.

But the real issue was pointed out by @3sky (see other answer). I needed to login as the jenkins user and try to ssh to my raspberry pi (which are both on the same machine).

So these are the steps i did:

1. Login via ssh to my raspberry pi

   > ssh -v pi@123.456.789.123 -p 330
2. Then I switched user to the jenkins user. After some google search i've found out how

   > sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
3. Then i ssh again to my own machine (where i already was ssh'ed in), so that i get the pop-up for thrusting this host once and for all!

   > ssh -v pi@123.456.789.123 -p 330

This solved my issue! Big thanks to 3sky for helping out!

Answer (score 4):

I need 4 more reputation point to comment, so I must write answer:)

Try use `-v` to debug ssh connection:

```
stage('connect ssh and remove files') {
    sshagent (credentials: ["0527982f-7794-45d0-99b0-135c868c5b36"]) {
        sh "ssh -v pi@123.456.789.123 -p 330 rm -rf /var/www/html/*"
    }
}
```

In another hand 
**Host key verification failed** means that the host key of the remote host was changed or you don't have the host key of the remote host. So at first try just `ssh -v pi@123.456.789.123` as Jenkins user, from Jenkins host.